# vue, vuex: load temporary child collection

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is a vue/vuex app and we have an object: `myObject`, that has a set of children: `myObject.kids`.

`.kids` is not loaded when the object is initially loaded by vuex.

Now I want to create a component that works on `.kids`.

What is the vue/vuex approach to this situation?

Should I create a root-level set to hold the kids or is there a way to load them (via ajax) into the myObject already in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want, load it vie ajax, create the property if it doesn't exist on component load, etc. The most important part is creating a reactive property, however. I would recommend the following:

```
this.$store.commit('SET_KIDS', payload)
```

Which would translate to a mutation in your store receiving a payload:

```
Vue.set(state.myObject, 'kids', payload)
```

This is important because the property needs to be reactive in order to be observable and for the store to record changes to the property.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  If `myObject.kids` starts life as undefined, will doing `Vue.set(state.myObject, 'kids', payload)` still cause it to become reactive?

Comment: @mtyson Yep. It will creative a reactive property on that object in your state.